# List item - layout crash, objects overlap

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to realize a simple layout for a list item. Design view of Android Studio show exactly what I want
[image]

However, at runtime, this is what I have on every single display.
[image]

To note that the last `TextView` (`@+id/messages_listview_item_modified_date`), is normally not visible; it became visible only under certain condition at runtime. Not sure it so relevant to be honest.

This is the xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="1"
              android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/messages_listview_heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_nick"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
      android:text="@string/messages_listview_item_nickname"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
      android:textColor="#ff99cc00"
      />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_title"
      android:text="@string/messages_listview_item_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#acacac"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
      android:layout_below="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_nick"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_date"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="@string/messages_listview_item_created_date"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"/>

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:contentDescription="@string/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
      android:src="@drawable/icon_user_messages"/>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="@string/messages_listview_item_body"
    android:textColor="#acacac"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textSize="16sp">
  </TextView>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_modified_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:text="@string/messages_listview_item_edited_date"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The outer LinearLayout is completely **useless**. It only increases the ViewGroup count. Rethink your layout using only the RelativeLayout to position your Views properly.

Comment: try using only linearLayout instead of Relative layout

Comment: @diva A single LinearLayout won't allow such a variety of View positions. While a RelativeLayout does.

Comment: @DerGolem you may use weight for the same

Comment: @diva **NO**. Weights only work in a **single direction** (width **or** height). Or you might recur to the **awful** level nesting. Which is even **worse** than the above layout.

Comment: m not saying to use horizontal and vertical views in same linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the linearlayout useless

you can use this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_nick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
        android:text="nickname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff99cc00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_title"
        android:text="title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="createddate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
        android:text="body"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_modified_date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textSize="16sp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_modified_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:text="editdate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work very well. http://i58.tinypic.com/52zwgp.png

Comment: It kinda of works if you replace `android:layout_below="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_title"` at  `android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_body"`. However, if body is large enough, `edited_date` is overlapped.

Comment: i updated my answer, for nickname and title you need to resize it to smaller or you can make the picture bigger

Answer (score 0):

I presume from picture 1 is exacly what you want to display

The issue may come from lower API on your real device.
To prevent that, try adding following things:

+In `android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_nick"` add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"`

+In `android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_title"` add
`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"`

+In `android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_date"` add 
`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

+In `android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"` add `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted these linee because I thought they were useless; from which API should I concern abuot them?
Btw, the result is still the same.